# Derive the KG field operator in terms of ladder operators

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, klein-gordon-equation

In Peskin and Schroeder, they skip a few steps to arrive at the KG field operator in Equation (2.25):
$$
\hat\phi(\vec x)=\int\dfrac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_{\vec p}}}\left(\hat a_{\vec p}e^{i\vec p\cdot\vec x}+\hat a^\dagger_{\vec p}e^{-i\vec p\cdot\vec x}\right)
$$

I want to get there step-by-step, and I'm running into problems with what I think is the convolution theorem, and that is the main point of my post.  I will develop the reasoning by which I end up with a wrong answer.  To begin, we assume in QM (with $\hbar=1$):
$$
[\hat x_i,\hat p_j]=i\delta_{ij}
$$

so it will be reasonable to assume in QFT:
$$
[\hat\phi(\vec x),\hat \pi(\vec y)]=i\delta^{(3)}(\vec x-\vec y)
$$

I have already shown that the canonical momentum in the KG field is $\pi=\dot \phi$, and I know the solutions to the KG equation are plane waves moving in either direction.  When I promote the field to an operator, it follows that the operators will be:
$$
\hat\phi=\hat A(\vec x)e^{ik_\mu x^\mu}+\hat B(\vec x)e^{-ik_\mu x^\mu}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\hat\pi=ik_0\hat A(\vec x)e^{ik_\mu x^\mu}-ik_0\hat B(\vec x)e^{-ik_\mu x^\mu}
$$

for some operators $\hat A$ and $\hat B$.  By requiring the commutation relation $[\hat\phi(\vec x),\hat \pi(\vec y)]=i\delta^{(3)}(\vec x-\vec y)$, I want to deduce that $\hat A$ and $\hat B$ must be the creation and annihilation operators appearing in Peskin's Equation (2.25) above.  (I have already assumed that this is the answer and checked that it is right, but I am doing it in the other direction, pretending I don't already know the answer.)  Since the commutation relation involves only the spatial part of position, I switch the signs in the exponentials (due to metric signature +---), and I proceed as follows:
\begin{align}
i\delta^{(3)}(\vec x-\vec y)&=\left[ \hat A(\vec x)e^{-i\vec k\cdot \vec x}+\hat B(\vec x)e^{i\vec k\cdot\vec x} \right]\!\left[ ik_0\hat A(\vec y)e^{-i\vec k\cdot y}-ik_0\hat B(\vec y)e^{i\vec k\cdot \vec y} \right]-\\
\qquad&\qquad-\left[ik_0\hat A(\vec y)e^{-i\vec k\cdot\vec y}-ik_0\hat B(\vec y)e^{i\vec k\cdot\vec y}\right] \!\left[\hat A(\vec x)e^{-i\vec k\cdot\vec x}+\hat B(\vec x)e^{i\vec k\cdot\vec x}\right]\\
&=ik_0\bigg\{ \hat A(\vec x)\hat A(\vec y)e^{-i\vec k\cdot (\vec x+\vec y)}-\hat A(\vec x)\hat B(\vec y)e^{-i\vec k\cdot (\vec x-\vec y)}+\\
\qquad&\qquad+\hat B(\vec x)\hat A(\vec y)e^{i\vec k \cdot(\vec x-\vec y)}-\hat B(\vec x)\hat B(\vec y) e^{i\vec k\cdot (\vec x+\vec y)} -\\
\qquad&\qquad-\hat A(\vec y)\hat A(\vec x)e^{-i\vec k\cdot (\vec x+\vec y)}+\hat A(\vec y)\hat B(\vec x)e^{i\vec k (\vec x-\vec y)}+\\
\qquad&\qquad+\hat B(\vec y) \hat A(\vec x)e^{-i\vec k\cdot (\vec x-\vec y)}+\hat B(\vec y)\hat B(\vec x)e^{i\vec k\cdot (\vec x+\vec y)}\bigg\}  \\
&=ik_0\bigg\{ [\hat B(\vec x),\hat A(\vec y)]e^{i\vec k\cdot (\vec x-\vec y)} +[\hat B(\vec y), \hat A(\vec x)]e^{-i\vec k (\vec x-\vec y)} \bigg\}    
\end{align}

Now it follows that:
$$
\dfrac{\delta^{(3)}(\vec x-\vec y)}{2k_0}= e^{i\vec k\cdot (\vec x-\vec y)}[\hat B(\vec x),\hat A(\vec y)]
$$

By referring to the well-known definition:
$$
\delta^{(3)}(\vec x-\vec y)=\int\dfrac{d^3k'}{(2\pi)^3}e^{i\vec k'\cdot(\vec x-\vec y)}
$$

I can tell that I need to convert to Fourier space to show that the RHS is a delta function because I already have an exponential in the requisite form: $e^{i\vec k\cdot(\vec x-\vec y)}$.  This is where I get confused.  If I am converting $\hat B(\vec x)$ and $\hat A(\vec y)$ to Fourier space, then I need to convert the exponentials involving $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ as well.  My thinking here is that if I only convert the operators with integrals over dummy variables $k'$ and $k''$, that will never hit the $k$ in the exponential term and I cannot obtian the delta function.    Thus, I write:

$$
\dfrac{\delta^{(3)}(\vec x-\vec y)}{2k_0}= \left[ \hat B(\vec x)e^{i\vec k\cdot \vec x} \right]\left[ \hat A(\vec y)e^{-i\vec k\cdot \vec y} \right]-\left[ \hat A(\vec y)e^{-i\vec k\cdot \vec y} \right]\left[ \hat B(\vec x)e^{i\vec k\cdot \vec x} \right]
$$

The convolution theorem says that the Fourier transform of a product is the convolution of the transforms.  (*Or does it?!?!*)  Since I don't know what the operators are, I will call the transforms $\tilde B(k')$ and $\tilde A(k'')$.  The transform of the exponential part is a delta function:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}[e^{i\vec k\cdot \vec x}](\vec k')&=\int d^3x'\,e^{-i\vec k'\cdot \vec x'}e^{i\vec k\cdot \vec x'}=(2\pi)^3\delta^{(3)}(\vec k'-\vec k)\\
\mathcal{F}[e^{-i\vec k\cdot \vec y}](\vec k'')&=\int d^3y'\,e^{-i\vec k''\cdot \vec y'}e^{-i\vec k\cdot \vec y'}=(2\pi)^3\delta^{(3)}(\vec k''+\vec k)\\
\end{align}

Now I can write the convolution of the transforms as:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}[\hat B(\vec x)e^{i\vec k\cdot \vec x}](\vec k')=(2\pi)^3\int d^3\tau \,\tilde B(\vec\tau)\delta^{(3)}(\vec\tau-(\vec k'-\vec k))=(2\pi)^3\tilde B(\vec k'-\vec k)\\
\mathcal{F}[\hat A(\vec y)e^{-i\vec k\cdot \vec y}](\vec k'')=(2\pi)^3\int d^3\sigma\,\tilde A(\vec\sigma)\delta^{(3)}(\vec\sigma-(\vec k''+\vec k))=(2\pi)^3\tilde A(\vec k''+\vec k)\\
\end{align}

Since the commutator of the ladder operators in k-space is $[\hat a_{\vec k},\hat a^\dagger_{\vec k'}]=(2\pi)^3\delta^{(3)}(\vec k-\vec k')$, there is no way I'm going to be able to infer that the commutator of $\tilde A$ and $\tilde B$ should be a Dirac delta function of position.  I'm also going to end up with too many factors of $2\pi$.  I have already blundered, and I think it must be around the step where I apply the convolution theorem.  Every textbook I look at arrives at Peskin's Equation (2.25) via the ansatz method, but I want to get there "honestly."  Where have I blundered?  Thanks.

Comment: You can't just write $\hat\phi=\hat A(\vec x)e^{ik_\mu x^\mu}+\hat B(\vec x)e^{-ik_\mu x^\mu}$.  If you want to express the field operator in terms of $k$, it has to be as a Fourier transform.  So you are starting your calculation with (among other things) integrals missing, and so the integrals and $\delta$-functions are never going to balance out.